# How to transform the Mongodb script to be equivalent to the java spring-data mongodb code

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, spring-data-mongodb

**I want to transform the below-given code to java code:**

```
db.cabinetStatusInfo.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        "fullPowerCount": 1,
        "cabinCount": 1,
        "fullPowerWarn": 1,
        "cabinetId": 1,
        "difference": {
            $cond: {
                if : { $eq: ["$cabinCount", null] },
                then: true,
                else : { 
                    $gte: [
                        { $multiply: [ 
                            { $toInt: { $ifNull: [ "$fullPowerCount", 0 ] } }, 5
                        ] }
                        ,
                        { $toInt: "$cabinCount" }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $match: {
        difference: true
    }
}
]);
```

I don't know how to use `$multiply`. Spring data's MongoDB documentation shows how to multiple a Field multiply a number, but does not show how to make the expression multiply with a number. Can you help me?

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(project("fullPowerCount", "cabinCount")
            .and("difference")
                .applyCondition(ConditionalOperators.Cond.newBuilder()
                .when(Criteria.where("cabinetCount").is(null))
                .then(true)
                .otherwise(
                        //how to use $multiply,help me
                        (toInt(ifNull("fullPowerCount").then('0'))) )
                ),

            match(Criteria.where("diffrence").is(true))
    );
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I am changing the following code snippet from your aggregation and what I feel is the correct way (the functionality is same). This is in the aggregation query's `$project` stage's `if` statement.

This is your code:

```
    "difference": {
        $cond: {
            if : { $eq: ["$cabinCount", null] },
```

The `if` clause is changed to:

```
if : { $eq: [ { $type: "$cabinCount" }, "null" ] },
```

This is because, though your code will work in `mongo` shell, it is difficult to convert into Spring Data MongoDB code (it takes more code and is complex). Note the `null` in MongoDB data is different from `null` in Java - there is no direct conversion. Null cannot be specified as it is in Java.

*The transformed code:*

```
ConditionalOperators.Cond conditon = 
    ConditionalOperators.Cond.newBuilder()
        .when(
            ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf(
                DataTypeOperators.Type.typeOf("cabinCount"))
                    .equalToValue("null")
        )
        .then(Boolean.TRUE)
        .otherwise(
            ComparisonOperators.Gte
                .valueOf(
                    ArithmeticOperators.Multiply.valueOf(
                        ConvertOperators.Convert.convertValueOf(
                             ConditionalOperators.IfNull.ifNull("fullPowerCount").then(Integer.valueOf(0))
                         ).to("int")
                    )
                    .multiplyBy(Integer.valueOf(5))
                )
            .greaterThanEqualTo(
                ConvertOperators.Convert.convertValueOf("cabinCount").to("int")
             )  
        );

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    Aggregation.project("cabinCount", "fullPowerCount")
        .and(
            condition
        )
        .as("difference")
);

MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "testDB");
AggregationResults<Document> results = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, "testColl", Document.class);
```

Comment: The code runs fine with Spring Boot 2.4.8 and MongoDB v4.2.8.